# How can I draw an Image onto another Image in the JDialog Window using Key Listener in Java?

Tags: java, image, swing, window, drawing

- **TL;DR:**

> App currently looks like IMAGE1, I want to show another .png file after key press, so it looks like in IMAGE2. How can I draw second image on my background image?

- **Detailed problem description:**

I run into trouble when trying to draw one image on top of another.

I have a Background Image loaded and it is visible in my JDialog window:

[image: IMAGE1 - BACKGROUND]

I also implemented Window, Mouse and Key Listeners for my Window, so it for example closes when mouse leaves the Window or when mouse is clicked - works perfectly.

But **I want to show another image (*small icon in the left upper corner of the window*) when user presses particular key** (*key listener also already works*), **so it looks more or less like this**:

[image: IMAGE2 - EXPECTED RESULT]

It is also possible that I'll need to show more icons later on, but **the problem is, that after I draw one Image, the other one is invisible (*and looks like in image 1*)**. Could you please guide me how can I achieve such effect? Maybe I should not be using conentPane at all?

- **Main Window Code:**

  ```
   public class MychoWindow extends JDialog {

      private Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();

   (... variables etc ...)

      public MychoWindow() {

         // Set the main properties of the Window:
         setTitle(WINDOW_TITLE);
         setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
         setResizable(false);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

         // Draw the background image:
         drawBackgroundImage();
         //  drawCatDefenseIcon();

         // Show the Window:
         centerWindowOnTheScreen();
         setVisible(true);

         // Set starting Variables:
         setWindowCenterX(getLocationOnScreen().x + WINDOW_WIDTH / 2);
         setWindowCenterY(getLocationOnScreen().y + WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2);

         // Add various Listeners:
         addWindowListener(new WindowListener());
         addMouseListener(new MouseListener());
         addKeyListener(new KeyboardListener());

      }
   }
  ```
- **Background Drawing Method:**

  ```
   private void drawBackgroundImage() {

      // Load Image from file:
      ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(MychoWindow.class.getResource(BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URL));

      // Transform it to Image to be able to resize it, and then transform it back to use it in JLabel:
      Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
      Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(WINDOW_WIDTH - IMAGE_FRAME_SIZE, WINDOW_HEIGHT - IMAGE_FRAME_SIZE,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way
      imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);

      // Add prepared image to the Label which is added to content pane:
      JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);

      // Add it to container:
      contentPane.add(label);
  }
  ```
- **Icon Drawing Method:**

  ```
   public void drawCatDefenseIcon() throws IOException {

      // TODO: SOMEHOW MAKE IT WORK
        (I tried to use the BufferedImage and Graphics2d here,
         I also tried the approach from above - drawBackgroundImage() method,
         but I just could not get it to work.)
   }
  ```
- **Key Listener** - Just in case:

  ```
   public class KeyboardListener extends KeyAdapter {

      @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {

         if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_K || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) {

            MychoWindow.setCatDefenseState(!MychoWindow.getCatDefenseState());

            System.out.println("SHOW THAT KEY WAS PRESSED");
         }
      }
   }
  ```

What is the best approach to achieve effect visible on attached IMAGE2?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: Better to use key bindings rather than a key listener.  You can draw directly on a component by overriding its paintComponent method (as per multiple similar questions and answers).

Comment: One solution could be to replace the Icon with a [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/). *I tried to use the BufferedImage and Graphics2d here,* - that is also a valid approach. You need to draw the second image on top of the first image. That would change the image permanently.

Comment: @camickr Thank you, CompoundIcon did the trick :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to add a second label to the background label.

Something like:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
background.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
```

Then later when you want to add the second Icon you use:

```
JLabel onTop = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
background.removeAll();
background.add( onTop );
background.revalidate();
```

Another approach could be to replace the existing Icon with a [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/).

Then the logic might be something like:

```
Icon original = background.getIcon();
Icon onTop = new ImageIcon(...);
CompoundIcon icon = new CompoundIcon(CompoundIcon.Axis.Z_AXIS, 0, CompoundIcon.LEFT, CompoundIcon.TOP, original, onTop);
background.setIcon( icon );
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw your comment earlier and tried CompoundIcon. I was able to make it work as desired :). I associated it with key listener and I repaint the content pane when key is released. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use one image as background image and other into picture box .It will help you
for example:

Picture Box have both Image and Background Image Property

to set Background Image you have to set pictureBox1.BackgroundImage=your Image;

and for Image property pictureBox1.Image=your Image;